# Как приложению на Java получить доступ к удалённой базе данных в PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

[image: Ошибка с подключением к базе данных]
Я хотел воспользоваться облачной базой данных Яндекса для тестирования своего приложения. Приложение интенсивно работает с базой данных, поэтому ему нужен обмен данными с базой данных разреженно, по постоянно (телеграм бот). Доступ к базен данных из-под pgAdmin есть, я там копался, выстраивал структуру таблиц, с которыми будет работать бот. Консоль Intellij IDEA видит базу данных. Но там надо добавить сертификат. Рылся в интернете, не нашёл, как выстраивают работу с приложений с удалённой базой данных на PostgreSQL. Выстроено вроде по инструкции яндекса, но это не помогает.
[image: Сертификат Яндекса в keystore есть]
Решение проблемы видится в том, чтобы передавать при данном подключении наличный сертификат яндекса из keystore. Но я не понимаю: как? Может потому, что очень устал разбираться с этой проблемой.

код для установления подключения:

```
String RulesConnection = "jdbc:postgresql://<yandex_ID>.yandexcloud.net/db1?&" +
            "targetServerType=master&ssl=true&sslmode=verify-full";
    String user = "postgres";
    String password = "<paasword>";
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        this.Rules = DriverManager.getConnection(RulesConnection,user,password);
        System.out.println("Connection with Rules DB established");
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
```

UPD.
Переписал код немножко и ошибка изменилась.

```
String RulesConn = "jdbc:postgresql://<yandex_ID>.yandexcloud.net:<port_number>/<DB_name>";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("targetServerType","<myType>");
        prop.setProperty("ssl","true");
        prop.setProperty("sslmode","verify-full");
        prop.setProperty("sslcert","C:\\AppData\\Roaming\\postgresql\\yandexcloudCA.der");
        prop.setProperty("user","postgres");
        prop.setProperty("password","<password>");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            Rules = DriverManager.getConnection(RulesConn,prop);
            System.out.println("Connection with Rules DB established");
            Rules = (Connection) conn.get();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
```

ошибка сменилась на

```
Could not open SSL root certificate file C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\root.crt
```

Запуск IDEA с правами администратора проблему не решил.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Собственно код, который позволил забраться в базу данных, хотя я буду ещё проверять.

```
String RulesConn = "jdbc:postgresql://<yandex_ID>.yandexcloud.net:<port_number>/<DB_name>";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("targetServerType","<myType>");
    prop.setProperty("ssl","true");
    prop.setProperty("sslmode","verify-full");  
  prop.setProperty("sslcert","C:\\AppData\\Roaming\\postgresql\\yandexcloudCA.der"); 
   prop.setProperty("sslrootcert","C:\\AppData\\Roaming\\postgresql\\root.crt.der");
    prop.setProperty("user","postgres");
    prop.setProperty("password","<password>");
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Rules = DriverManager.getConnection(RulesConn,prop);
        System.out.println("Connection with Rules DB established");
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
```